# Django IntegerField with Choice Options (how to create 0-10 integer options)

Tags: python, django

I want to limit the field to values *0-10* in a select widget.

```
field=models.IntegerField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES)
```

I could just write out all the choices tuples from *(0,0),(1,1)* on, but there must be an obvious way to handle this.

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: max_length specifies the width of the column, not the max value.  You want max_length=2

Comment: Comment about IntegerField `max_length`, in Django 1.1X and 2.X it is useless, see [django.db.models.fields.IntegerField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.2/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1789)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use a Python list comprehension:

```
CHOICES = [(i,i) for i in range(11)]
```

This will result in:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10,10)]
```

Comment: range(11) will get you 0-10. +1 nonetheless

Answer (score 7):

As well as @Torsten has mentioned, you could improve it by:

```
field = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 10), range(1, 10))), unique=True)
```

But remember this will gives you from 1 to 9. Put range (1,11) if you want until 10